# AngularJS increment value for id attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, increment

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in y">
    <td>
         <div ng-attr-id="{{getId()}}"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
         <div ng-attr-id="{{getId()}}"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
         <div ng-attr-id="{{getId()}}"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to have an id that starts from 1 for the first `<td>` element and then increments one for each `<td>` element.

By doing in the controller:

```
$scope.getId = function () {
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

I get

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in y track by $index">
  <td>
    <div ng-attr-id="{{$index + 1}}"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

For nested loops you can define a new track value and combine with `$index` or for static three elements you can write this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in y track by $index">
  <td>
    <div ng-attr-id="{{$index*3 + 1}}"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ng-attr-id="{{$index*3 + 2}}"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ng-attr-id="{{$index*3 + 3}}"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `track by $index` did but it worked! What does *3 signify

Comment: From the documentation, `$index: iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)`. In each step you have three element, that's why you have to multiply index by 3 to have incremental indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$index` variable of `ngRepeat` directive.

> `$index`: iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
>
> [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

So, you can do :

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{$index + 1}}"></div>
```

We use `$index + 1` to start from 1